# SQL, how to use Dynamic Condition logics?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, conditional-statements

When you need Dynamic WHERE Clause I can use;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_sel_Articles]
      @articleId            INT              = NULL
    , @title            NVARCHAR(250)    = NULL
    , @accessLevelId    INT              = NULL
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT *
     FROM table_Articles Art
     WHERE
          (Art.ArticleId = @articleId OR @articleId IS NULL)
          AND (Art.Title LIKE '%' + @title + '%' OR @title IS NULL)
          AND (Art.AccessLevelId = @accessLevelId OR @accessLevelId IS NULL)
END
```

So, I am able to invoke this procedure -for example- **ONLY** by ArticleId

```
EXEC [sp_sel_Articles] @articleId = 3
```

But, sometimes I'll need to invoke by AccessLevelId and sometimes **NOT by an EXACT VALUE**. For example, I'll need MORE THAN the given accesslevelId or LESS THAN.

Current procedure can **ONLY** handle the **EXACT** value by using

```
Art.AccessLevelId = @accessLevelId
```

Could also be possible to give the **CONDITION** type as well as the value into the procedure? It may seem very odd in this example but please just bear with me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_sel_Articles]
          @articleId            INT              = NULL
        , @title            NVARCHAR(250)    = NULL
        , @accessLevelId    INT              = NULL
        , **@accessLevelIdCondition**
    AS
    BEGIN
         SELECT *
         FROM table_Articles Art
         WHERE
              (Art.ArticleId = @articleId OR @articleId IS NULL)
              AND (Art.Title LIKE '%' + @title + '%' OR @title IS NULL)
              AND (Art.AccessLevelId **@accessLevelIdCondition** @accessLevelId OR @accessLevelId IS NULL)
    END
```

Perhaps an Function can be used, I don't know. Since, there will be at least 20 Procedure that will require this flexibility, I'll need a better, more global solution as much as possible rather than writing IF ELSE condition in every procedure.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't call your SPs sp_.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this [www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) before applying

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_sel_Articles] 
              @articleId            INT              = NULL 
            , @title            NVARCHAR(250)    = NULL 
            , @accessLevelId    INT              = NULL 
            , @accessLevelIdCondition varchar(100)
        AS 
        BEGIN 
                DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000)
    SET @SQL='
         SELECT * 
         FROM table_Articles Art 
         WHERE 
              (Art.ArticleId = '+cast(@articleId as varchar(100))+' OR '+cast(@articleId as varchar(100))+'IS NULL) 
              AND (Art.Title LIKE ''%'' + @title + ''%'' OR @title IS NULL) 
              AND (Art.AccessLevelId '+@accessLevelIdCondition+ cast(@accessLevelId as varchar(100))+' OR '+cast(@accessLevelId as varchar(100))+' IS NULL) '
    EXEC(@sql)
        END
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably need to use dynamic SQL to pass in the operator. Or you could pass in two values, e.g.

```
@MinAccessLevelID INT,
@MaxAccessLevelID INT

...
WHERE (
   (@MinAccessLevelID IS NULL AND @MaxAccessLevelID IS NULL)
   OR 
   (AccessLevelID >= @MinAccessLevelID AND AccessLevelID <= @MaxAccessLevelID)
)
```

When you want exact (e.g. only 3), just pass 3 into both values. When you want anything above 3, pass 20000000000 into the @Max param, or 0 if you want everything below 3.

But you'll find as these permutations get more complex, you are going to be better off just using dynamic SQL (and with `optimize for ad hoc workloads` set, this will be better for plan cache reuse and thwarting parameter sniffing as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can always make a dynamic query with just making a querystring

```
execute ('select count(*) from table' )
```

So with the params entered in your stored procedure, you can also form up a querystring which you can execute.

Comment: Apparently someone doesn't like dynamic SQL, otherwise I'm not clear on the down-votes. As the OP said he may have >=, >, =, <, <= for every column in the where clause. Dynamic SQL seems like a more viable option as those combinations increase...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case statement - it can look a little funny if not formatted correctly but you can try something like:

```
SELECT Columns FROM SomeTable
WHERE 1 = CASE
              WHEN @SomeOption = '<>' AND SomeValue >= @SomeMinParam AND SomeValue <= SomeMaxParam THEN 1
              WHEN @SomeOption '=' AND SomeValue = @SomeMinParam THEN 1
              ELSE 0
          END
```

(though as Aaron pointed out - the <> you pass in doesn't really reflect the comparison operators in the statement - change this to something meaningful :))

in your case:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_sel_Articles]
    @articleId            INT              = NULL,
    @title            NVARCHAR(250)    = NULL,
    @MinaccessLevelId    INT              = NULL,
    @MaxaccessLevelId     INT          = NULL,
    @accessType       varchar(5)       = '<>'
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT *
 FROM table_Articles Art
 WHERE
      (Art.ArticleId = @articleId OR @articleId IS NULL)
      AND (Art.Title LIKE '%' + @title + '%' OR @title IS NULL)
      AND 1 = CASE 
                  WHEN @accessType = '<>' AND (Art.AccessLevelId = @MinaccessLevelId OR @accessLevelId IS NULL) THEN 1
                  WHEN @accessType = '=' AND (Art.AccessLevelId >= @MinaccessLevelId OR Art.AccessLevelId <= @MaxaccessLevelId) THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
              END
END
```

Maybe use a bit @CompareAccessLevelToMin instead of a varchar() for the @accessType param. Still has the trouble of not telling you what setting it to 'false' means though.

Comment: I don't think this gets the results you expect, for two reasons: (1) <> should yield < and > not <= and >= (2) SomeValue can't be > `@SomeParam` and < `@SomeParam` at the same time.

Comment: I updated it to add the missing max param - I think though you could just use NULL for the max to specify that you want it to only use Min, it makes it a little more easy to read without having to view the definition of the sproc (then again you probably need to open it to see the possible parameter values) - maybe naming the parameter '@accessLevelMustEqualMin' and making it a bit is more clear? I'd probably do it the way you did it Aaron - with the NULL, to be honest :)

Comment: I'm talking about your first code snippet. My comment was posted before you added the procedure.

Comment: Thank you. This one is the first I thought. But there could be <=, >=, =, < or > for EVERY field with all procedures. I was trying to avoid this approach but nevertheless I might have to use this after all.

Comment: Aarons might be more useful then - because it seems more logical - you pass two of the same value to get a single item. I suppose it depends on what you feel comfortable with - but don't forget to comment the hell out of it for the poor sod that has to maintain it :D

Comment: Right and if you need < or > then you pass MAX-1 or MIN+1 etc. to avoid having to code < and <= separately. Which works for integers, at least.